# How can i checking if the user is logged?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am checking if the user is logged

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin')
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) =>{
      console.log('message1', user)
      if (user) {
        console.log('exist')
      } else {
        console.log('not exist')
      }
    });
```

but i only get error: Error: FIREBASE_ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Admin SDK, which has no concept of a signed-in user. All code in the Admin SDK runs under an administrative account, not under a Firebase Authentication user's credentials.

If you want to determine what user is logged in on a client, that is then communicating with the process that runs the Admin SDK, you can do so by [getting the ID token for the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) on the client, sending that to the server, and [decoding and verifying the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) on the server.

Also see:

- [Node.JS Firebase Auth - Is there a way to keep a user session like with client side Firebase Auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444426/node-js-firebase-auth-is-there-a-way-to-keep-a-user-session-like-with-client-s/51444533#51444533)
- [How to check if user is authenticated in Firebase and Express/Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643768/how-to-check-if-user-is-authenticated-in-firebase-and-express-node-js/50645472#50645472)

Comment: I added links to the relevant documentation, which includes sample code for many platforms, and some links to similar questions.